# Continuous integration of Salesforce with CircleCI

Tags: apex, managed-package, continuous-integration, ci

I want to setup our Continuous Integration with CircleCI. I want our GitHub to deploy our code to a central test org anytime a developer pushes changes to run all the Apex tests and make sure that nothing is broken so we can deploy to a packaging org. I have found some repositories online like [this](https://github.com/CodeScience/circle-start) or [this](https://github.com/ngs/apex-circleci-example) that have the configuration setup but my CircleCI builds are still failing. It seems to be simple enough but I must be missing a simple step. Can someone either share a working setup or a reliable source that can help it get setup please?

One more thing is that, unfortunately, we have not made the jump to DX yet. So it needs to work with pre-DX tools and orgs. Our current infrastructure is working with ANT and and-salesforce.jar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a series of blogs on setting up continuous integration with CircleCI and SFDX:

- [CircleCI and Salesforce DX](https://www.ktema.org/2018/02/02/salesforce-dx-circleci/)
- [Testing on Multiple Org Types with CircleCI and Salesforce DX](https://www.ktema.org/2018/03/17/circleci-sfdx-multiple-org-shapes/)
- [Integration Testing Off-Platform Code with Salesforce DX and CircleCI](https://www.ktema.org/2018/03/27/integration-testing-salesforce-dx-simple-salesforce/)

I also have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/davidmreed/circleci-sfdx-examples) with a number of examples using SFDX and CircleCI alone, with multiple org types, with Lightning Testing Service, and with PMD or Codecov.io.

I use this setup for some [side](https://github.com/davidmreed/septaTrains) [projects](https://github.com/davidmreed/DMRNoteAttachmentImporter) that are up and running on this toolchain if a fully working example is useful.

Your question sounds like you're also interested in continuous *deployment*, which does go further than any of my examples. While it is not a huge step to add, it tends to be a little more case-specific and less generalizable. A more specific question there might yield more tailored answers.